# How to do table pagination when some data is calculated?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am working on a page with a modest data table (1500 rows).

I have been trying to optimise the load of the page that shows this table, but loading all 1500 rows slows the page load down to ~10 seconds.

I have asked other SO questions to try to optimise my page and dataset, but everyone suggests pagination of the data.

My problem is that the data is not all available immediately - some of it is calculated.

So my table has several columns. Some are loaded directly from a mysql database - name, price, etc. But two columns are calculated.

For each row, I need to download the data from the database, populate the direct data such as name or price, but then make calculations on the data to fill the remaining columns.

The table has to allow sorting by each column, so I cant see any way to allow this, other than to have the full 1,500 row table visible at once. Otherwise, how to sort the table by one of the computed columns?

So how would it be possible to paginate that table?

I know how to paginate if the data was all fixed, but using  ORDER BY and LIMIT, but the calculated rows dont allow me to do this for all columns.

The calculations cant be made and stored separately, because the data changes every day, and the user can choose what calculations to do on the data by way of form inputs.

Comment: "loading all 1500 rows slows the page load down to ~10 seconds." - Why? Where is the performance bottleneck?

Comment: Have you tried [Datatables](https://datatables.net/)? It is easy to integrate and solves the pagination and sorting issues automatically.

Comment: Datatables still requires that ALL the data be within the html. It then applies its own sorting and pagination. But loading my page with every data row is too slow to load.

Comment: Have you confirmed that omission of the calculated values speeds things up?

Comment: Why do you need to `render` all 1500 rows? Get the data on the server side (1500 isn't slow to load) then send down 25 for the current page. Datatables supports ajax requests, you can use this aspect of it.

Comment: I dont need to show 1500. That is the point of my question. I want to paginate the data, but how to allow the user to sort by data that is calculated and paginate it at the same time? I cant show the user 25 rows and allow them to sort by 25 rows, if there are 1000 rows with other data more relevant to their sort column.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider OFFSET + LIMIT in SQL : [LIMIT+OFFSET](http://sql.sh/cours/limit)

For first page you can show first 100 rows

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

For the second page you can use offset 100 and show next 100 rows

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
```

And so on.

Also you can use some open source cache, for example [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis). Cache systems works faster, but you'll need to save your data there and read instead of your DB.

Comment: I am combining LIMIT and OFFSET into the LIMIT command only (LIMIT100,100). But how does this solve ordering the data by data that doesnt exist in the table and needs calculated?

Comment: ahhh, okey, I understood you problem. @Richard probably you have a difficult sql request. Could you add it in the description of problem.

Comment: @Richard which DB do you use ? MySQL, PostgreSQL, ... ? Probably you can cut some part of your request and save it as a command on DB side ?